# Elegant way to format single string having multiple call to `format()` (format chaining)

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting

I am trying to substitute a variable using `format()` and then format the resulting string using `format()`.

This is what I ended up doing:

```
>>> '{:^50}'.format("Missing files for device : {0}".format(var))
'          Missing files for device : abc          '
```

where `var` is a variable holding `'abc'`. Is there a better way to get the same result?

Answer (score 3):

In your case, there is a simpler way:

```
>>> "Missing files for device : {0}".format(var).center(50)
'          Missing files for device : abc          '
```

Calling format twice is not necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

You may `join` the strings and pass the joined string to `format` function as:

```
>>> center_content = ["Missing files for device :", "abc"]

>>> '{:^50}'.format(' '.join(center_content))
'          Missing files for device : abc          '
```